# Invalid column error while using native query in JPA repository

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

There are two related entities in the project.
The trouble is in Flag field of Comment entity.
When Flag field is present in Comment entity - the query in JPA repository fails - Error Code:

> 17006 Message: Invalid column name.

When I comment this field inside the entity (just to check)- everything works fine.
How can I handle it properly using native queries?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TN_COMMENTS")
public class Comment implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "COMMENT_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "COMMENT_SEQ", sequenceName = "NT_COMMENT_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TARGET_TYPE")
    private TargetType targetType;
    
    @Column(name="TARGET_ID")
    private Long targetId;
    
    @Column(name="COMMENT_BODY")
    private String commentBody;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name="COMMENT_CHANGED_FLAG",referencedColumnName="FLAG_VALUE")),
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value="'COMMENT_CHANGED_FLAG'",referencedColumnName="FLAG_NAME"))})
    private Flag commentType;
    
    @Column(name="COMMENT_DATE")
    private Date commentDate;
    
    @Column(name="COMMENT_USER")
    private String commentUser;
    
    @Column(name="COMMENT_USER_ROLE")
    private String commentUserRole;
    
    ...
}
    
    
@Entity
@Table (name = "TN_D_FLAG_DESCRIPTION")
public class Flag implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private FlagId flagId;
    
    @Column(name="FLAG_DESCRIPTION")
    private String flagDescription;

    public String getFlagDescription() {
        return flagDescription;
    }

    public void setFlagDescription(String flagDescription) {
        this.flagDescription = flagDescription;
    }

    public void setFlagId(FlagId flagId) {
        this.flagId = flagId;
    }

    public FlagId getFlagId() {
        return flagId;
    }
    
    ...
}


@Embeddable
public class FlagId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="FLAG_NAME")
    private String flagName;
    
    @Column(name="FLAG_VALUE")
    private Long flagValue;
    ...
}
    
    
public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment, Long> {

    @Query( value = "SELECT c.* " +
            "FROM tn_comments c " +
            "JOIN tn_s_target_types t on t.code = c.target_type " +
            "WHERE c.target_type = ?1 AND c.target_id = ?2 ",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<Comment> getCommentsByTargetTypeAndTargetId(String targetType, Long targetId);

}
```

Comment: How does the generated SQL look like and please include the whole stacktrace